# Why doesn't my $('id').css('property: value'); apply its style?

Tags: css, navigation, border

I'm trying to make a jQuery if statement that says:
 If a user is on the specified page, then apply specified style; in this case it's putting a bottom-border on an anchor tag's id.

```
// index.php - referenced html
...
<link href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript' />
<style type="text/javascript">
@import url('js/active-links.js');
</style>
...
<ul>
    <li><a id="home" href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a id="other1" href="#">OTHER1</a></li>
    <li><a id="other2" href="#">OTHER2</a></li>
</ul>
...


// active-link.js 
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.URL.indexOf('index.php') >= 0) {
        $('#home').css('border-bottom: 18px solid #9cd588');
                                            }
                       });
```

Ideally, I will have this apply to each link with an else if stating the same thing. Currently it's not doing anything.

Comment: Are you sure your condition evaluates correctly?

Comment: Not entirely, any ideas? It works with another script I had:
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.URL.indexOf("contact.php") >= 0) {
   $('#contact').attr('src','img/m_contact.png');
   $('#portfolio').mouseover(function() {
      ...

Comment: You're not doing it right, now I figured out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Shouldn't the below statement work?
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#home').css('border-bottom', '18px solid #9cd588');
         });

Comment: are you aware that you have multiple severe HTML issues (what's with the `type="text/javascript"` everywhere?)? you'd probably want to solve these first before addressing problems in the JS or CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching the problem wrong.

In the server side, determine the active link from the menu, and add an `active` classname to the active menu item.

```
$active = "Home";
...
echo "<li";
if ($active == "Home") { echo " class=\"active\" "; }
echo ">Home</li>";
```

Then, in your CSS, without any conditions:

```
.active { border-bottom: 18px solid #9cd588; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
$('#home').css('border-bottom', '18px solid #9cd588');
```

Comment: Wrong, the second one will fail. `borderBottom`.

Comment: The top one works. http://jsfiddle.net/GScxM/1/ Are you sure your condition evaluates correctly?